# Excel VBA. Sum duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have this table:

```
Column1 | Column2 
-----------------
Name1   |  3,0 
Name1   |  2,0 
Name2   |  5,0 
Name2   |  6,0 
etc...
```

I need VBA macros, which will result in:

```
Column1 | Column2 
-----------------
Name1   |  5,0 
Name2   |  11,0
```

Steps:
1. sum a column2 
2. delete duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

Will put new list in D and E, assumes list is on current sheet and in A:B

```
Sub te()

Range("D1:" & Range("E1").End(xlDown).Address).ClearContents
Range("A1:" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Copy Destination:=Range("D1")
Range("D1:" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

For Each cell In Range("D1:" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Address)
    temp = 0
    For Each c In Range("A1:" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address)
        If cell.Value = c.Value Then
            temp = temp + c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next

    For Each c In Range("D1:" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Address)
        If cell.Value = c.Value Then
             c.Offset(0, 1).Value = temp
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```